# Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in descpage.php on line 221

Tags: warnings, implode

I am getting the following error:

`Warning: implode() [function.implode]: Invalid arguments passed in /descpage.php on line 221`

I read through the site and cannot see this covered.

Could you please have a look and see if you can see anything that would cause these issues.

This is from an old amzon store script, I don't think the programmer is updating it anymore.

Here is the full code from the page:

`

```
function push($myarray,$text){
    $myarray[] = $text;
}
if ($Details[Address]) {
    push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text1]</b> ".($Details[Address][0])); 
}
if ($Details[AmazonMaximumAge]) {
    if ($Details[AmazonMaximumAge] < "24") {
        $maxyears = sprintf("%.0f", $Details[AmazonMaximumAge][0]);
        push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text2]</b> $maxyears ".$language_text[miscellaneous1]);
    } else{
        $maxyears = sprintf("%.0f", $Details[AmazonMaximumAge][0] / 12);
        push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text2]</b> $maxyears ".$language_text[miscellaneous2]);
    }
}
if ($Details[ManufacturerMaximumAge]) {
    if ($Details[ManufacturerMaximumAge] < "24") {
        $maxyears = sprintf("%.0f", $Details[ManufacturerMaximumAge][0]);
        push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text91]</b> $maxyears ".$language_text[miscellaneous1]);
    } else{
        $maxyears = sprintf("%.0f", $Details[ManufacturerMaximumAge][0] / 12);
        push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text91]</b> $maxyears ".$language_text[miscellaneous2]);
    }
}
if ($Details[AmazonMinimumAge]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text3]</b> ".($Details[AmazonMinimumAge][0]));
if ($Details[ApertureModes]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text4]</b> ".($Details[ApertureModes][0]));
if ($Details[AspectRatio]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text5]</b> ".($Details[AspectRatio][0]));
if ($Details[AudienceRating]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text6]</b> ".($Details[AudienceRating][0]));
if ($Details[AudioFormat]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text7]</b> ".($Details[AudioFormat][0]));
if ($Details[BackFinding]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text8]</b> ".($Details[BackFinding][0]));
if ($Details[BandMaterialType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text9]</b> ".($Details[BandMaterialType][0]));
if ($Details[BatteriesIncluded]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text10]</b> ".($Details[BatteriesIncluded][0]));
if ($Details[Batteries]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text11]</b> ".($Details[Batteries][0]));
if ($Details[BatteryDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text12]</b> ".($Details[BatteryDescription][0]));
if ($Details[BatteryType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text13]</b> ".($Details[BatteryType][0]));
if ($Details[BezelMaterialType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text14]</b> ".($Details[BezelMaterialType][0]));
if ($Details[Binding]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text15]</b> ".($Details[Binding][0]));
if ($Details[Brand]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text16]</b> ".($Details[Brand][0]));
if ($Details[CalendarType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text17]</b> ".($Details[CalendarType][0]));
if ($Details[CameraManualFeatures]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text18]</b> ".($Details[CameraManualFeatures][0]));
if ($Details[CaseDiameter]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text19]</b> ".($Details[CaseDiameter][0]));
if ($Details[CaseMaterialType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text20]</b> ".($Details[CaseMaterialType][0]));
if ($Details[CaseThickness]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text21]</b> ".($Details[CaseThickness][0]));
if ($Details[CaseType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text22]</b> ".($Details[CaseType][0]));
if ($Details[CDRWDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text23]</b> ".($Details[CDRWDescription][0]));
if ($Details[ChainType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text24]</b> ".($Details[ChainType][0]));
if ($Details[ClaspType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text25]</b> ".($Details[ClaspType][0]));
if ($Details[ClothingSize]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text26]</b> ".($Details[ClothingSize][0]));
if ($Details[Color]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text27]</b> ".($Details[Color][0]));
if ($Details[Compatibility]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text28]</b> ".($Details[Compatibility][0]));
if ($Details[ComputerHardwareType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text29]</b> ".($Details[ComputerHardwareType][0]));
if ($Details[ComputerPlatform]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text30]</b> ".($Details[ComputerPlatform][0]));
if ($Details[Connectivity]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text31]</b> ".($Details[Connectivity][0]));
if ($Details[ContinuousShootingSpeed]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text32]</b> ".($Details[ContinuousShootingSpeed][0]));
if ($Details[Country]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text33]</b> ".($Details[Country][0]));
if ($Details[CPUManufacturer]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text34]</b> ".($Details[CPUManufacturer][0]));
if ($Details[CPUSpeed]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text35]</b> ".($Details[CPUSpeed][0]));
if ($Details[CPUType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text36]</b> ".($Details[CPUType][0]));
if ($Details[Cuisine]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text37]</b> ".($Details[Cuisine][0]));
if ($Details[DelayBetweenShots]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text38]</b> ".($Details[DelayBetweenShots][0]));
if ($Details[Department]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text39]</b> ".($Details[Department][0]));
if ($Details[DeweyDecimalNumber]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text40]</b> ".($Details[DeweyDecimalNumber][0]));
if ($Details[DialColor]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text41]</b> ".($Details[DialColor][0]));
if ($Details[DialWindowMaterialType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text42]</b> ".($Details[DialWindowMaterialType][0]));
if ($Details[DigitalZoom]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text43]</b> ".($Details[DigitalZoom][0]));
if ($Details[DisplaySize]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text44]</b> ".($Details[DisplaySize][0]));
if ($Details[DVDRWDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text45]</b> ".($Details[DVDRWDescription][0]));
if ($Details[EAN]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text46]</b> ".($Details[EAN][0]));
if ($Details[ESRBAgeRating]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text47]</b> ".($Details[ESRBAgeRating][0]));
if ($Details[ExternalDisplaySupportDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text48]</b> ".($Details[ExternalDisplaySupportDescription][0]));
if ($Details[FabricType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text49]</b> ".($Details[FabricType][0]));
if ($Details[FaxNumber]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text50]</b> ".($Details[FaxNumber][0]));
if ($Details[Feature]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text51]</b> ".($Details[Feature][0]));
if ($Details[FirstIssueLeadTime]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text52]</b> ".($Details[FirstIssueLeadTime][0]));
if ($Details[FloppyDiskDriveDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text53]</b> ".($Details[FloppyDiskDriveDescription][0]));
if ($Details[Format]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text54]</b> ".($Details[Format][0]));
if ($Details[GemType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text55]</b> ".($Details[GemType][0]));
if ($Details[GraphicsCardInterface]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text56]</b> ".($Details[GraphicsCardInterface][0]));
if ($Details[GraphicsDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text57]</b> ".($Details[GraphicsDescription][0]));
if ($Details[GraphicsMemorySize]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text58]</b> ".($Details[GraphicsMemorySize][0]));
if ($Details[HardDiskCount]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text59]</b> ".($Details[HardDiskCount][0]));
if ($Details[HardDiskSize]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text60]</b> ".($Details[HardDiskSize][0]));
if ($Details[HasAutoFocus]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text61]</b> ".($Details[HasAutoFocus][0]));
if ($Details[HasBurstMode]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text62]</b> ".($Details[HasBurstMode][0]));
if ($Details[HasInCameraEditing]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text63]</b> ".($Details[HasInCameraEditing][0]));
if ($Details[HasRedEyeReduction]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text64]</b> ".($Details[HasRedEyeReduction][0]));
if ($Details[HasSelfTimer]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text65]</b> ".($Details[HasSelfTimer][0]));
if ($Details[HasTripodMount]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text66]</b> ".($Details[HasTripodMount][0]));
if ($Details[HasVideoOut]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text67]</b> ".($Details[HasVideoOut][0]));
if ($Details[HasViewfinder]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text68]</b> ".($Details[HasViewfinder][0]));
if ($Details[Height]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text69]</b> ".($Details[Height][0]));
if ($Details[HoursOfOperation]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text70]</b> ".($Details[HoursOfOperation][0]));
if ($Details[Hours]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text71]</b> ".($Details[Hours][0]));
if ($Details[IncludedSoftware]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text72]</b> ".($Details[IncludedSoftware][0]));
if ($Details[IncludesMp3Player]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text73]</b> ".($Details[IncludesMp3Player][0]));
if ($Details[Ingredients]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text74]</b> ".($Details[Ingredients][0]));
if ($Details[IsAutographed]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text75]</b> ".($Details[IsAutographed][0]));
if ($Details[ISBN]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text76]</b> ".($Details[ISBN][0]));
if ($Details[IsFragile]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text77]</b> ".($Details[IsFragile][0]));
if ($Details[IsLabCreated]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text78]</b> ".($Details[IsLabCreated][0]));
if ($Details[IsMemorabilia]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text79]</b> ".($Details[IsMemorabilia][0]));
if ($Details[ISOEquivalent]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text80]</b> ".($Details[ISOEquivalent][0]));
if ($Details[IssuesPerYear]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text81]</b> ".($Details[IssuesPerYear][0]));
if ($Details[KeyboardDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text82]</b> ".($Details[KeyboardDescription][0]));
if ($Details[Label]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text83]</b> ".($Details[Label][0]));
if ($Details[LegalDisclaimer]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text84]</b> ".($Details[LegalDisclaimer][0]));
if ($Details[Length]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text85]</b> ".($Details[Length][0]));
if ($Details[LineVoltage]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text86]</b> ".($Details[LineVoltage][0]));
if ($Details[MacroFocusRange]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text87]</b> ".($Details[MacroFocusRange][0]));
if ($Details[MagazineType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text88]</b> ".($Details[MagazineType][0]));
if ($Details[Manufacturer]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text89]</b> ".($Details[Manufacturer][0]));
if ($Details[ManufacturerLaborWarrantyDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text90]</b> ".($Details[ManufacturerLaborWarrantyDescription][0]));
if ($Details[ManufacturerMinimumAge]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text92]</b> ".($Details[ManufacturerMinimumAge][0]));
if ($Details[ManufacturerPartsWarrantyDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text93]</b> ".($Details[ManufacturerPartsWarrantyDescription][0]));
if ($Details[MaterialType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text94]</b> ".($Details[MaterialType][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumAperture]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text95]</b> ".($Details[MaximumAperture][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumColorDepth]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text96]</b> ".($Details[MaximumColorDepth][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumFocalLength]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text97]</b> ".($Details[MaximumFocalLength][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumHighResolutionImages]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text98]</b> ".($Details[MaximumHighResolutionImages][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumHorizontalResolution]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text99]</b> ".($Details[MaximumHorizontalResolution][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumLowResolutionImages]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text100]</b> ".($Details[MaximumLowResolutionImages][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumResolution]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text101]</b> ".($Details[MaximumResolution][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumShutterSpeed]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text102]</b> ".($Details[MaximumShutterSpeed][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumVerticalResolution]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text103]</b> ".($Details[MaximumVerticalResolution][0]));
if ($Details[MaximumWeightRecommendation]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text104]</b> ".($Details[MaximumWeightRecommendation][0]));
if ($Details[MemorySlotsAvailable]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text105]</b> ".($Details[MemorySlotsAvailable][0]));
if ($Details[MetalStamp]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text106]</b> ".($Details[MetalStamp][0]));
if ($Details[MetalType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text107]</b> ".($Details[MetalType][0]));
if ($Details[MiniMovieDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text108]</b> ".($Details[MiniMovieDescription][0]));
if ($Details[MinimumFocalLength]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text109]</b> ".($Details[MinimumFocalLength][0]));
if ($Details[MinimumShutterSpeed]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text110]</b> ".($Details[MinimumShutterSpeed][0]));
if ($Details[Model]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text111]</b> ".($Details[Model][0]));
if ($Details[ModemDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text112]</b> ".($Details[ModemDescription][0]));
if ($Details[MonitorSize]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text113]</b> ".($Details[MonitorSize][0]));
if ($Details[MonitorViewableDiagonalSize]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text114]</b> ".($Details[MonitorViewableDiagonalSize][0]));
if ($Details[MouseDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text115]</b> ".($Details[MouseDescription][0]));
if ($Details[NativeResolution]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text116]</b> ".($Details[NativeResolution][0]));
if ($Details[Neighborhood]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text117]</b> ".($Details[Neighborhood][0]));
if ($Details[NetworkInterfaceDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text118]</b> ".($Details[NetworkInterfaceDescription][0]));
if ($Details[NotebookDisplayTechnology]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text119]</b> ".($Details[NotebookDisplayTechnology][0]));
if ($Details[NotebookPointingDeviceDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text120]</b> ".($Details[NotebookPointingDeviceDescription][0]));
if ($Details[NumberOfDiscs]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text121]</b> ".($Details[NumberOfDiscs][0]));
if ($Details[NumberOfIssues]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text122]</b> ".($Details[NumberOfIssues][0]));
if ($Details[NumberOfItems]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text123]</b> ".($Details[NumberOfItems][0]));
if ($Details[NumberOfPages]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text124]</b> ".($Details[NumberOfPages][0]));
if ($Details[NumberOfPearls]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text125]</b> ".($Details[NumberOfPearls][0]));
if ($Details[NumberOfRapidFireShots]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text126]</b> ".($Details[NumberOfRapidFireShots][0]));
if ($Details[NumberOfStones]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text127]</b> ".($Details[NumberOfStones][0]));
if ($Details[NumberOfTracks]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text128]</b> ".($Details[NumberOfTracks][0]));
if ($Details[OpticalZoom]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text129]</b> ".($Details[OpticalZoom][0]));
if ($Details[PearlLustre]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text130]</b> ".($Details[PearlLustre][0]));
if ($Details[PearlMinimumColor]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text131]</b> ".($Details[PearlMinimumColor][0]));
if ($Details[PearlShape]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text132]</b> ".($Details[PearlShape][0]));
if ($Details[PearlStringingMethod]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text133]</b> ".($Details[PearlStringingMethod][0]));
if ($Details[PearlSurfaceBlemishes]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text134]</b> ".($Details[PearlSurfaceBlemishes][0]));
if ($Details[PearlType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text135]</b> ".($Details[PearlType][0]));
if ($Details[PearlUniformity]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text136]</b> ".($Details[PearlUniformity][0]));
if ($Details[PhoneNumber]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text137]</b> ".($Details[PhoneNumber][0]));
if ($Details[PhotoFlashType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text138]</b> ".($Details[PhotoFlashType][0]));
if ($Details[PictureFormat]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text139]</b> ".($Details[PictureFormat][0]));
if ($Details[Platform]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text140]</b> ".($Details[Platform][0]));
if ($Details[PriceRating]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text141]</b> ".($Details[PriceRating][0]));
if ($Details[ProcessorCount]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text142]</b> ".($Details[ProcessorCount][0]));
if ($Details[PublicationDate]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text143]</b> ".($Details[PublicationDate][0]));
if ($Details[Publisher]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text144]</b> ".($Details[Publisher][0]));
if ($Details[ReadingLevel]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text145]</b> ".($Details[ReadingLevel][0]));
if ($Details[RegionCode]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text146]</b> ".($Details[RegionCode][0]));
if ($Details[ReleaseDate]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text147]</b> ".($Details[ReleaseDate][0]));
if ($Details[RemovableMemory]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text148]</b> ".($Details[RemovableMemory][0]));
if ($Details[ResolutionModes]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text149]</b> ".($Details[ResolutionModes][0]));
if ($Details[RingSize]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text150]</b> ".($Details[RingSize][0]));
if ($Details[RunningTime]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text151]</b> ".($Details[RunningTime][0]));
if ($Details[SalesRank]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text194]</b> ".($Details[SalesRank][0]));
if ($Details[SecondaryCacheSize]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text152]</b> ".($Details[SecondaryCacheSize][0]));
if ($Details[SettingType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text153]</b> ".($Details[SettingType][0]));
if ($Details[SizePerPearl]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text154]</b> ".($Details[SizePerPearl][0]));
if ($Details[Size]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text155]</b> ".($Details[Size][0]));
if ($Details[SoundCardDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text156]</b> ".($Details[SoundCardDescription][0]));
if ($Details[SpeakerDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text157]</b> ".($Details[SpeakerDescription][0]));
if ($Details[SpecialFeatures]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text158]</b> ".($Details[SpecialFeatures][0]));
if ($Details[StoneClarity]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text159]</b> ".($Details[StoneClarity][0]));
if ($Details[StoneColor]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text160]</b> ".($Details[StoneColor][0]));
if ($Details[StoneCut]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text161]</b> ".($Details[StoneCut][0]));
if ($Details[StoneShape]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text162]</b> ".($Details[StoneShape][0]));
if ($Details[StoneWeight]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text163]</b> ".($Details[StoneWeight][0]));
if ($Details[Studio]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text164]</b> ".($Details[Studio][0]));
if ($Details[SubscriptionLength]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text165]</b> ".($Details[SubscriptionLength][0]));
if ($Details[SupportedImageType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text166]</b> ".($Details[SupportedImageType][0]));
if ($Details[SystemBusSpeed]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text167]</b> ".($Details[SystemBusSpeed][0]));
if ($Details[SystemMemorySizeMax]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text168]</b> ".($Details[SystemMemorySizeMax][0]));
if ($Details[SystemMemorySize]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text169]</b> ".($Details[SystemMemorySize][0]));
if ($Details[SystemMemoryType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text170]</b> ".($Details[SystemMemoryType][0]));
if ($Details[TheatricalReleaseDate]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text171]</b> ".($Details[TheatricalReleaseDate][0]));
if ($Details[TotalDiamondWeight]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text172]</b> ".($Details[TotalDiamondWeight][0]));
if ($Details[TotalExternalBaysFree]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text173]</b> ".($Details[TotalExternalBaysFree][0]));
if ($Details[TotalFirewirePorts]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text174]</b> ".($Details[TotalFirewirePorts][0]));
if ($Details[TotalGemWeight]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text175]</b> ".($Details[TotalGemWeight][0]));
if ($Details[TotalInternalBaysFree]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text176]</b> ".($Details[TotalInternalBaysFree][0]));
if ($Details[TotalMetalWeight]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text177]</b> ".($Details[TotalMetalWeight][0]));
if ($Details[TotalNTSCPALPorts]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text178]</b> ".($Details[TotalNTSCPALPorts][0]));
if ($Details[TotalParallelPorts]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text179]</b> ".($Details[TotalParallelPorts][0]));
if ($Details[TotalPCCardSlots]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text180]</b> ".($Details[TotalPCCardSlots][0]));
if ($Details[TotalPCISlotsFree]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text181]</b> ".($Details[TotalPCISlotsFree][0]));
if ($Details[TotalSerialPorts]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text182]</b> ".($Details[TotalSerialPorts][0]));
if ($Details[TotalSVideoOutPorts]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text183]</b> ".($Details[TotalSVideoOutPorts][0]));
if ($Details[TotalUSB2Ports]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text184]</b> ".($Details[TotalUSB2Ports][0]));
if ($Details[TotalUSBPorts]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text185]</b> ".($Details[TotalUSBPorts][0]));
if ($Details[TotalVGAOutPorts]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text186]</b> ".($Details[TotalVGAOutPorts][0]));
if ($Details[VariationDenomination]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text187]</b> ".($Details[VariationDenomination][0]));
if ($Details[VariationDescription]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text188]</b> ".($Details[VariationDescription][0]));
if ($Details[Warranty]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text189]</b> ".($Details[Warranty][0]));
if ($Details[WatchMovementType]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text190]</b> ".($Details[WatchMovementType][0]));
if ($Details[WaterResistanceDepth]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text191]</b> ".($Details[WaterResistanceDepth][0]));
if ($Details[Weight]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text192]</b> ".($Details[Weight][0]));
if ($Details[Width]) push ($descriptors, "<b>$language_text[details_text193]</b> ".($Details[Width][0]));

$ProductDescription = implode("<br>",$descriptors);

$tmpl->SetTemplate("productpage");
echo $tmpl->ParseTemplate();
```

?>`

The line mentioned in the error message is line 221 below:

`$ProductDescription = implode("<br>",$descriptors);`

The script seems to work fine if I hash this line out.

Can anyone see why it would do this?

Thanks in advance for your help and time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is "only" a warning, because the $descriptors variable was never initialized or filled with a value.

Add a $descriptors = array(); in before line 4 and everything will work as expected

```
function push($myarray,$text){
    $myarray[] = $text;
}
if(!isset($descriptors)) {
    $descriptors = array();
}
if ($Details[Address]) {
```

Comment: I've added the code as SomeoneYouDontKnow put forward, which got rid of the error, but the description the code is meant to pull from amazon still isn't being shown?

Comment: Do you think the code is just too old, and needs completely rewriting?

Comment: Update, the content looks like it's actually being fed through now.

Comment: Thank you SomeoneYouDontKnow, it looks like this has done the trick.